# Plot all the values in a row against the index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a daframe `df`:

```
    beat1   beat2   beat3   beat4   beat5   beat6   beat7   beat8   beat9  
0  0.6839  0.8879  0.7543  0.4805  0.8528  0.6982  0.5520  0.6154  0.6579   
1  1.0380  0.4868  0.3099  0.4994  0.7509  0.4649  0.5080  0.4040  0.7537   
2  0.7116  0.8063  0.6754  0.7365  0.9517  0.6420  0.8108  0.9082  0.7132   
3  0.7296  0.7389  0.7227  0.7623  0.7424  0.7457  0.8250  0.7064  0.7792   
4  0.8912  0.8617  0.8189  0.8118  0.6574  0.8882  0.6544  0.8296  0.9344
```

Now, I want to plot all the values in a given row as a function of index values `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`. I can achieve this using a following code:

```
for i in df.index:
    vals = df.loc[i]
    for val in vals:
        plt.scatter(i, val,c='g')

plt.show()
```

However, there must be a way to do the same without using nested for loops since it is slow for larger dataframes and I need to do this multiple times. Any ideas?

Comment: Feel free to upvote the chosen answer as well to show additional gratitude

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply the scatter plot to each row:

```
df.apply(lambda x: plt.scatter(x.index, x, c='g'))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
plt.scatter(df.index.values.repeat(len(df.columns)), df.values.ravel())
```

[image]

---

```
df.stack().reset_index(0).plot.scatter('level_0', 0)
```

[image]